# How to solve this SSL error while using twitter api?

Tags: python

```
import tweepy 
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api =tweepy.API(auth)

results = []
keyword = "nft"
tweet = api.search_tweets(keyword)
for i in tweet:
    results.append(i.text)

print(results)
```

For studying, I got an API from devtwitter.
Then, I've tried to do some crawling from twitter but this error is keep showing.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='free-proxy-list.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

i 've tried a lot of ways after googling but it didn't work.
are there any solutions?
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Why is the error showing a `free-proxy-list.net`? If you are using a proxy, then the problem is either from the proxy itself, or because the Twitter API doesn't work well with that proxy.

Comment: Have you tried using Twitter's own API directly? 
Link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api